# Debian SAS Not Attaching As SD device (another does)

Tags: debian, sas, scsi

I have an x4100 with 4 drive slots 3 drives are part of the RAID 1E. On the RAID Array I have installed Debian. I am using the 4th slot for accessing file storage drives. The HP 600GB drive attaches successfully as an sd device. The HITACHI 146GB drive does not attach as an sd device.

Here is the dmesg for HP 600GB which worked

```
[ 1690.575618] mptsas: ioc0: attaching ssp device: fw_channel 0, fw_id 3, phy 3, sas_addr 0x5000cca0438c25d9
[ 1690.584098] scsi 4:0:5:0: Direct-Access     HP       EG0600FBVFP      HPD9 PQ: 0 ANSI: 5
[ 1690.587021] sd 4:0:5:0: Attached scsi generic sg5 type 0
[ 1690.587955] sd 4:0:5:0: [sdc] 1172123568 512-byte logical blocks: (600 GB/559 GiB)
[ 1690.588213] sd 4:0:5:0: [sdc] Write Protect is off
[ 1690.588215] sd 4:0:5:0: [sdc] Mode Sense: f7 00 10 08
[ 1690.588558] sd 4:0:5:0: [sdc] Write cache: enabled, read cache: enabled, supports DPO and FUA
[ 1690.624829]  sdc: sdc1
[ 1690.627303] sd 4:0:5:0: [sdc] Attached SCSI disk
[ 1786.818313]  end_device-4:5: mptsas: ioc0: removing ssp device: fw_channel 0, fw_id 3, phy 3,sas_addr 0x5000cca0438c25d9
[ 1786.818323]  phy-4:3: mptsas: ioc0: delete phy 3, phy-obj (0x00000000cbdf9139)
[ 1786.818342]  port-4:5: mptsas: ioc0: delete port 5, sas_addr (0x5000cca0438c25d9)
[ 1786.819447] sd 4:0:5:0: [sdc] Synchronizing SCSI cache
[ 1786.866762] scsi target4:0:5: mptsas: ioc0: delete device: fw_channel 0, fw_id 3, phy 3, sas_addr 0x5000cca0438c25d9
```

Here is the dmesg for HITACHI 146GB that did not work

```
[ 1843.665188] mptsas: ioc0: attaching ssp device: fw_channel 0, fw_id 3, phy 3, sas_addr 0x5000cca000286b05
[ 1843.678988] scsi 4:0:6:0: Direct-Access     HITACHI  H101414SCSUN146G SA23 PQ: 0 ANSI: 5
[ 1843.686873] scsi 4:0:6:0: Attached scsi generic sg5 type 0
[ 1843.694526] mptbase: ioc0: LogInfo(0x30030501): Originator={IOP}, Code={Invalid Page}, SubCode(0x0501) cb_idx mptbase_reply
```

Because the second drive does not attach as an sd device, I am not able to use lsblk or fdisk.

How can I correct this? Or is this SAS drive simply not compatible with Debian?

Comment: Have you considered the possibility that that disk is dead? It certainly looks dead.

Comment: Hmm. You are probably right. I actually have 4 drives. One works. Two show dmesg like above and the 3rd does not give any dmesg at all. They are probably just dead.

Comment: Googling that error message certainly gives no other result than the drive is faulty.